# Array not rendering as a collection of children Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a hook, `Prompt`. one of the props is an Object containing some field names as keys.
I create a form using these fields and some `<input>`s. This is what the hook `Fields` returns.
It is rendered from an array. I log this array at `log-A`. Here is what I get:

[image: y no work]

This makes me believe that this is an array of react components.

There is a function that I am trying to make that gets the results of this form.
To do this, I want to go through the children of the `<div>` with `ref={fieldsRef}`. Since this just contains a list of react components, I thought I could just get the children of it and use `React.Children.toArray()`.
This does not work.

```js
const Prompt = (props) => {

    //...

    const Fields = () => {
        let fieldKeys = Object.keys(props.fields);
        let fields = [];
        for ( let fieldKey of fieldKeys ) {
            fields.push(
                <div key={fieldKey.toString()}>
                    <div className={"field-name"}>
                        {props.fields[fieldKey]}
                    </div>
                    <input spellCheck="false"/>
                </div>
            );
        }

        console.log(fields); //log-A

        return (
            <div ref={fieldsRef}>
                {fields}
            </div>
        );
    }

    const getForm = () => {
        console.log(fieldsRef); //log-B
        let current = fieldsRef.current.children;
        let children = React.Children.toArray(current);
        return 0;
    }

    //...

}
```

at `log-B`, the output is a `div`. It's `current` has `children` that are in a [image].

I get an error when trying to access the children of this.

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDivElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

What am I doing wrong, to not be able to access these children and convert to an array using `React.Children.toArray(<children>)`?

Comment: Change `{fields}` to `{() => fields}`?

Comment: @Dominik This causes nothing to be rendered from `fields`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like getForm() is considering `{fields}` itself to be an object, rather than the array you are trying to reference. Try moving your `fields` variable declaration into the Prompt() scope instead of the nesting it under Fields().

Also, consider using the [React Developer Tools Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) for Chrome, it can really help with debugging issues with props and hooks.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't solve the issue. Thanks for the tip in the dev tools extension - will download now.